# What does "end site" mean?

Tags: rfc, terminology

I see that many IETF RFC documents use "end site" term.
However I cannot find exact definition of an "end site".

Does anybody have a reasonable explanation of what is an "end site"?
In particular I am interested whether "end site" can be considered as being in one location like a building, or it can be spread in many locations.

Comment: Can you be specific which RFC's you're talking about?

Comment: I am talking about [RFC 6177](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6177) and [RFC 3177](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3177)

Comment: @MaksymBondarenko that was a lucky guess of mine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of [RFC 6177](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6177), *"IPv6 Address Assignment to End Sites"*, an end site would be a **single location** with its own dedicated IP service provision.

That definition *might* encompass multiple buildings if they're all on one site and sharing the same upstream IP service, and interconnected via an inter-building LAN.

For a multi-location SME who takes separate internet service for each location from the *same* ISP, that ISP might allocate a /48 for the SME as a whole, but then allocate a /56 from within that /48 for each physical location.

This aggregation of multiple end sites within one larger subnet allows for simpler firewall policies, VPN settings, etc.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak! I was briefly reading RFC 6177, but I couldn't derive from its content that end site means a single location or a set of buildings in a similar location. Can you point me to a place in RFC 6177 that has such an explanation?

Comment: I also found the following definition at [RIPE-450](https://www.ripe.net/publications/docs/ripe-450/at_download/pdf):
"An End Site is defined as an End User (subscriber) who has a business or legal relationship (same
or associated entities) with a service provider that involves:
 that service provider assigning address space to the End User
 that service provider providing transit service for the End User to other sites
 that service provider carrying the End User's traffic
 that service provider advertising an aggregate prefix route that contains the End
User's assignment"

Comment: However it doesn't suggest anything about the End User being located at one place and not distributed across different locations, like different cities or different city districts.

Comment: @MaksymBondarenko I think it's just supposed to be "implicit", based on the common understanding of the word "site".  I know one of the authors of 6177 well, I'll ask next time we speak.